# Setting JSON response in ListView

Tags: android, json

```
if (status == 200) {
    String result = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
    Log.d("Response", result);
    ArrayAdapter < String > adapter = new ArrayAdapter < String > (getActivity(),
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, result);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```

I am unable to set my response into my List. I get my response as 
`{
    "Appointments": [{

       "Name": "Kevin",
    }, {
       "Name": "John",
    }]
}`

How would i set my name parameter in the listView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How would i set my name parameter in the listView.

At a glance. Third parameter of `ArrayAdapter` should be collection but you are passing only simple String. According to your `JSON` i recommend you:

- Create own object that will represent **Person** with properties(name,
  age, etc.)
- Parse `JSON` and create collection of persons
- Set collection to ListAdapter

### Example:

```
public class Person {

    private String name;
    ...

    // getters and setters

    @Override
    public String toString() {
       return this.name;
    }
}
```

Then, you need to parse `JSON` and get proper data:

```
List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<Person>();
Person person = null;
JSONObject root = new JSONObject(sourceString);
JSONArray appointments = root.getJSONArray("Appointments");
JSONObject child = null;
for (int i = 0; i < appointments.length(); i++) {
   child = appointments.getJSONObject(i);
   if (child != null)
      person = new Person();
      person.setName(child.getString("Name"));
      persons.add(person);
   }
}
```

Then initialise `ListAdapter`:

```
new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), layout, persons);
```

and now you got it.

### Note:

Reason why i'm overriding `toString()` method is that since you are using default ArrayAdapter with build-in Android layout each object in your List will be converted to String and will be shown in ListView but if i don't override `toString()` it won't return person's name but string representation of object that is human-unreadable string.

Comment: Don't forget to override the `Person.toString()` to return the name of the person since `toString()` is what the adapter will call on each of the `Person` objects in the persons collection you give to the adapter.

Comment: @Sajmon: Can u help me out in a issue of passing data from AsyncThread to Fragment...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15731173/null-pointer-exception-in-my-listener

Comment: @Kevin thanks man, but now it is solved.maybe in future i will help you again :)))

Comment: @Sajmon: could have a look at this thread, actually i am very confused over fragments.... thanks Sajmon

Answer (score 1):

1. `result` is a String containing the entire response. You need to parse or split that string into the items that you want.
2. You need to give your adapter the items (either as a list or an array). Right now you've created an adapter but haven't provided it any data via the constructor or any setter.

I suggest you read more about ListViews and Adapters on the Android developers site.